# I want to make a text field editable only when a check box is selected in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, actionlistener, itemlistener

I am using Netbeans, and I want it so a text field is only editable when the user clicks the check box. I have it so when they select the check box it makes the text field editable, but how do I make it so when they de-select the check box the text field becomes un-editable again?

The code I used to make it editable is -

```
private void chk4By6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    txt4By6.setEditable(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html), so that you can enable or disable the `JTextField` depending on if `JCheckBox` is `SELECTED` or `DESELECTED` respectively.

A sample program :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ModifyTextField 
{
    public static void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MODIFY TEXTFIELD");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

        final JTextField tfield = new JTextField(10);
        tfield.setEnabled(false);

        final JCheckBox cbox = new JCheckBox("Enable TEXTFIELD", false);

        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener()
        {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
            {
                tfield.setEnabled(ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            }
        };
        cbox.addItemListener(itemListener);

        contentPane.add(cbox);
        contentPane.add(tfield);

        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Outcome :

[image: DESELECTED] and [image: SELECTED]

Comment: nitpick: you don't need an if-else block to set the enabled property :-)

Comment: @kleopatra : Nah, that else-if is to set it back to disabled if you will deselect the checkbox. If i will keep only one, then if it's enabled once, it will remain as is :-) Won't it ? The OP wants both conditions to be satisfied, if `JCheckBox` is selected `JTextField` is enabled and `JCheckBox` is deselected `JTextField` be disabled.

Comment: hint: the required enabled property has the same value as the expression tested in the if block :-)

Comment: @kleopatra : Please do elaborate today no hints :-) My head is really not working today to be true, please, might be I will learn something that is missing from my CPU :-)

Comment: Though the best i can think of right now is this `tfield.setEnabled(true);
               if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
                {
                    tfield.setEnabled(false);
                }` to write inside the itemStateChanged(...) method, that will remove the else-if part and only if will remain.

Comment: field.setEnabled(ie.getStateChange() == SELECTED)

Comment: @kleopatra : LOL, too true, I never use to think like this, my bad, only for one reason. To make the code easily readable and easy to grasp. But this does gives the same thing true and false. Doing this way no doubt, removed many unnecessary conditions. Edited my answer likewise. Thankyou

Comment: or field.setEditable(ie.getStateChange() == SELECTED)

Answer (score 1):

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Read the whole thing if you really want to learn how this works.

Comment: +1, for the link. I will go with the Tutorial to get my things done, for better clarity   :-). But it will be much wiser if you go with `ItemListener`, so that you can catch both `SELECTED` and `DESELECTED` events for enabling and disabling the `JTextField`

Comment: @GagandeepBali Action vs. ItemListener is mainly a matter of taste and context, f.i. binding or application frameworks might make it easier to use the one or other :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered:

```
private void chk4By6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    txt4By6.setEditable(!txt4By6.isEditble());
}
```

Or maybe even... (assuming chk4By6 is a swing checkbox)

```
private void chk4By6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    txt4By6.setEditable(chk4By6.isSelected());
}
```

And a third method might be:

```
private void chk4By6ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    txt4By6.setEditable(chk4By6.isSelected());
}
```

Comment: The third method is the best, IMHO.  ActionListeners are the way to go.

Comment: -1 for repeating the OP's incorrect lead (listening to low level mouse events instead of semantic events)